# LWC: How to call a community page on button click in LWC?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

How to call different community page from LWC page on button click that exists on a community page without passing the URL?

```
navigateToWebPage() {
        // Navigate to a URL
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: 'http://salesforce.com'
            }
        },
        {
            // Replaces the current page in your browser history
            // with the URL
            true
        });
```

Is there any way by which I just pass the community page name and it calls that?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me -

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'becomepartner',
            },
        });
```

Comment: `standard__namedPage` page reference depreciated from summer 19,https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm . u r org running under which release?

Answer (score 0):

- 1st prepare object with api name and other parameters to be send
- 2nd generate url
- 3rd launch the
  page.

  **step -1**

  ```
        this.pageReference = {
           type: 'comm__namedPage',
           attributes: {
               name: 'SitePageB__c' //api name of community page
           },
           state: {
               recordId: this.account.id //passing Id to another page to be used further
            },
       };
  ```

  **step 2**

  ```
   if (this.pageReference) {
           this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.pageReference)
               .then(url => {
                   this.href = url;
               });
       }
       evt.stopPropagation();
       evt.preventDefault();
  ```

  **step 3**

  ```
   if (this.pageReference) {
       this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.pageReference);
   }
  ```