# Navigate to an experience site page from lwc component on button click event

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, navigationmixin.navigate, lightningnavigation

We have Aura experience Site.
It has multiple pages. in one of page named sitePageA, I have lwc component, in lwc component , I am showing buttons. On the button Click I want to open another page - sitePageB of the same site.

**Expectation** -When this method is executed, it should open a new window that will render/open Page-B of the Experience Aura site.

Api Name of page B- 'SitePageB'

Tried this on button click of lwc component of page SitePageA-

```
handleRowAction() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: 'SitePageB',
            }
        });
    }
```

No error is coming in the console. when used this code on button method.

FYI: we have multiple site, hope that's not an issue with NavigationMix.

I also wanted to share one variable value to another page.

Comment: What are you expecting and what is not working? From your question, it's not clear what isn't actually working for you currently. Could you please [edit] your question to add some clarity.

Comment: I have added what I want to acheive. Problem is not finding the correct document and example of Navigation to one page to another site page

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261388/lwc-how-to-call-a-community-page-on-button-click-in-lwc @CallumMacErlich same question was upvoted and my question were downvote. though have better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting the answer after investing many hours. Will save someones precious hours

- 1st prepare object with api name and other parameters to be send
- 2nd generate url
- 3rd launch the
  page.

  **step -1**

  ```
        this.pageReference = {
           type: 'comm__namedPage',
           attributes: {
               name: 'SitePageB__c' //api name of community page
           },
           state: {
               recordId: this.account.id //passing Id to another page to be used further
            },
       };
  ```

  **step 2**

  ```
   if (this.pageReference) {
           this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.pageReference)
               .then(url => {
                   this.href = url;
               });
       }
       evt.stopPropagation();
       evt.preventDefault();
  ```

  **step 3**

  ```
   if (this.pageReference) {
       this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.pageReference);
   }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to navigate to a Object page in community:

```
navigateToObjectPage(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'ApproachedCompany__c',
            actionName: 'home',
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to navigate to an Standard page with in Community :

```
    navigateToStdPage(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            name: 'sitePageB__c',
        }
    });
}
```

NB: 'ApproachedCompany__c' is an object in my dev org where i tried this and 'sitePageB__c' is a standard page i created in my community